# SDL2 window size is bigger than it should be

Tags: c, window, size, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a window, let's say 400x400:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
Uint32 mode = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(400, 400, mode, &window, &renderer))
    return 2;
if (!window || !renderer)
    return 2;
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
SDL_Event event;
int quit = 0;
while (!quit)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            quit = 1;
    }
}
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();
```

I see a window filled with black pixels. However, the window's size is 500x500 withouth borders, and 502x540 with them, but why?

Comment: On Windows, the OS may stretch your window in case you are using a high DPI monitor. Try `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_HIGHDPI_DISABLED, "1")`

Comment: @LoveMetal It works, thank you. If you post is as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the OS may stretch your window in the case when you are using a high DPI monitor. You can disable this stretching using:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_HIGHDPI_DISABLED, "1")
```